# sorting dates in XML using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to sort the dates in xml using xslt and my date element is validated in xsd with datatype as date below is my xml and xsl

XML

```
<Trade xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Symbol xsi:type="TradedSymbol"    Type="Swap">
 <Economic xsi:type="EconomicLeg">
  <Leg xsi:type="IRLegGeneratedFixed">
    <Schedule xsi:type="ScheduleGeneratorFixed">
     <Date>2014-06-17</Date>
    </Schedule>
  </Leg>
 </Economic>
</Symbol>
<Symbol xsi:type="TradedSymbol"    Type="Swap">
 <Economic xsi:type="EconomicDetailIRLeg">
  <Leg xsi:type="IRLegFloat">
   <Schedule xsi:type="ScheduleGeneratorFloat">
    <Date>2018-06-17</Date>
   </Schedule>
  </Leg>
 </Economic>
</Symbol>
<Symbol xsi:type="TradedSymbol" Type="Floor">
 <Economic xsi:type="EconomicDetailIRLeg">
  <Leg xsi:type="IRLegFloat">
   <Schedule xsi:type="ScheduleGeneratorFloat">
    <Date>2000-06-17</Date>
  </Schedule>
 </Leg>
 </Economic>
</Symbol>
</Trade>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="fiExoticStructuredDeal">
<fixedIncomeExoticDeal>
  <frontOfficeDealDescription>Empty   decription</frontOfficeDealDescription>
 <component>
   <frontOfficeComponentType>
    <optionDetails>
    <optionStyle>European</optionStyle>
     <optionDates>
   <adjustedDate>
<xsl:for-each select="/Trade/Symbol/Economic/Leg/Schedule">

   <xsl:sort select="concat(substring-before(Date,'-'), substring-before(substring-after(Date,'-    '),'-'),substring-after(substring-after(Date,'-'),'-'))" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = last()"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
                                            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose> 

</xsl:for-each>

          </adjustedDate>
     </optionDates>
</optionDetails>
</frontOfficeComponentType>
    </component>

    </fixedIncomeExoticDeal>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able sort the Date using xslt.It always gives me the last date in Schedule element.
It will be great if someone let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: `<Date>2014-06-17</EndDate>` - this is not valid XML. Actually, there are many other XML errors.

Comment: When I fix the XML to be well formed and the XSLT template to be `match="/"` instead of `name="..."` and test this locally it works correctly for me.  What XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:sort select="Date" order="ascending"/>
```

Comment: I checked the same by copying the xml and xsl in w3schools.